# Assembly 'EDCLR' references assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089 error

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr

I'm try to create clr function in c# with this code:

```
[SqlFunction]
        public static string Decrypt(string Input)
        {
            var test = "";
            var url = "http://www.url/feed/";
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                //MessageBox.Show("Title:" + feed.Title.Text);
                //MessageBox.Show("Uri:" + feed.Links[0].Uri);
                foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                {
                    test=item.Title.Text;
                }
            }
            return test;
        }
```

when try add that to sql server assembly with this script:

```
create assembly behzad
from 'd:\EDCLR.dll'
```

i get this error:

> Assembly 'EDCLR' references assembly 'system.servicemodel,
>   version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.',
>   which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to
>   locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same
>   location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has
>   failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please
>   load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your
>   request.

how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. **ServiceModel** is not a supported .NET Framework Library for SQLCLR. Meaning, it is not included in SQL Server's CLR host. In such cases, one needs to manually load, via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, the Assembly. BUT,
2. Starting in SQL Server 2012, you cannot reference / load **ServiceModel** as that version is the first to be linked to CLR v 4.0 in which **ServiceModel** became a mixed mode Assembly. Only pure MSIL Assemblies are allowed.

You will need to find a different way to accomplish this. One way is to use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`.

This issue has been documented on Stack Overflow here:

- [(Unfixable) Assembly exists on SQL Server 2014 but it claims it doesn't have it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313954/unfixable-assembly-exists-on-sql-server-2014-but-it-claims-it-doesnt-have-it/40314364#40314364)
- [Register CLR function (WCF based) in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173120/register-clr-function-wcf-based-in-sql-server-2012)
- [SQL CLR - Migration from 2008 R2 to 2012.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567028/sql-clr-migration-from-2008-r2-to-2012)

More info here:

- [SQL Server: "CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Test' failed because assembly 'Test' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653838/sql-server-create-assembly-for-assembly-test-failed-because-assembly-test/36654479#36654479)
- [SQL Server custom CLR fails with error "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598524/sql-server-custom-clr-fails-with-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-o/31615762#31615762)